# how to add clickable images on instant search with algolia

Tags: search, clickable, algolia

Hi I have made a instant search with images but I want them to click the image and redirect them to a different page. I have been searching for ages and I'm so stuck. what do I need to add in the index and how to add it in javascript.

I use json for the indexes.

add href to a image.
I use javascript and html.

Answer (score 0):

In the index, you need to have one attribute for the **url** of the link and one attribute for the **src** of the image.

```
var myRecord = {
    url: "/this-cat.html",
    image: "/cat-pic.png",
    ... // other attributes
}
```

Then, you need to use both in the template:

```
templates: {
    item: '<a href="{{{url}}}"><img src="{{{image}}}" /></a>'
}
```

Here's a [template](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/blob/master/docs/examples/e-commerce/search.js#L32) that does this from the [instantsearch e-commerce example](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/tree/master/docs/examples/e-commerce).